# iOS - Killing app makes you to build and run it on Xcode again

Tags: ios, xcode, build

After building and running app in Xcode, if app kills(either by user or by OS) it doesn’t open until i build and run it again in Xcode on the device. it has similar behavior on simulator and real device.

My Xcode version is 11.5 (11E608c). I reinstalled it on same Mac and also test it on other Macs but the problem still insists.

It seems to be Xcode bug. but Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an `Environment Variable` in my `Schema` which **Xcode** provides its value when app runs with Xcode. if app runs without Xcode the value would not be provided.
Obviously this is **Xcode** flaw that has no warning for developers about this.
providing the value from another resource, fixed the problem.

my code was:

```
guard let someVar = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["SOME_VAR"] else {
    fatalError("Could not get someVar value")
}
```